# MDX sum from date dim to now

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I am trying to create a calculated measure showing the SUM of a measure over a period of time FROM a current member of a date dimension TO now.

The following code is pretty bad but I hope it will give you an idea:

```
With Member [Measures].[NumberFromDate] as (
    sum(
        [Date].currentMember:STRTOMEMBER(Format(Now() , '[Date]\.&[yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0]' )
    ), [Measures].[Number]
)
```

In my schema Date is a Dimension with a single Level Date of type Date.
This mdx code give me an error "Cannot find MDX member '[Date]'".

Answer (score 0):

Try strToSet instead:

```
With Member [Measures].[NumberFromDate] as (
    sum(
        strToSet(
           '[Date].currentMember:[Date].[' & Format(Now() ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0') & ']'
        ) 
    )
, [Measures].[Number]
)
```

Here is a very similar request on MSDN:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fdee9f45-8383-4446-b022-e9e877477aec/mdx-date-format

I'm a bit unsure if your format sring is ok. Is this really the string used in your cube?

> 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0'